# When I should use repository pattern in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, design-patterns

I'm reading about the Laravel Best practices to reduce the code duplication as much as I can, then I read about the repository pattern and I'm following [this technique](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/) but when I was exploring the https://github.com/akaunting/akaunting open source software for accounting, I saw there is nothing related to respository pattern. I really got confused, so when should I use the repository pattern? if it is helpful when why the good projects not use that pattern? or if there is something better than repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

This is true for every design pattern: never start with wanting to implement a specific design pattern.

Start by never using the repository pattern (or any other pattern) and when you feel like your controllers are getting really big or your code is getting really hard to maintain take a look at what design pattern might solve your issue.

The given package does not contain that pattern because the people who made it did not need an extra layer of abstraction or chose other abstraction solutions.

Always start simple.